# FreeForm Error message

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I get this error message on submit of my form. Does anyone know what it means?

Invalid form id(s) submitted.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your form code.

Comment: Are you seeing this error all the time or just when you submit the form and then use your back button to test again?

Comment: Thanks for you response ... No it seems to be even when I hit the site for the first time.

Comment: I seem to have got it working although no idea why my fix works ... the message id attribute was set to 'message-input'. As soon as I changed this to just 'message' the form started working again. I have no idea why. I have updated main post with a screen shot showing code of the working form with id of 'message' on the text area element.

Comment: Now it has stopped working again showing original error message of 'invalid form id's' ... I have made no changes so no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Please paste all your code including the opening tags for the form.

Comment: try to add "redirect 301 /index.html http://www.yoursite.com/index.php" into your .htaccess file. And please check what do you have in form action parameter (in html output). + your EE version and Freeform version.

Comment: Can we see the complete block of form code? What versions of FF and EE?